# What's the difference between @component and <x-component/> in Blade for Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-9

I learned I can create components for Blade in Laravel 9 in two ways:

```
@component('components.myComponent')
@endcomponent
```

and also

```
<x-myComponent/>
```

What method is preferred?

Comment: The first one is [Laravel 5.5 Blade "Slots" syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#components-and-slots), the other [Laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#slots). I think there is no other difference than how it is written.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 7 introduced an overhauled Blade components system. Since that point the documentation has not mentioned `@component`. However, the [Laravel 7 release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/releases#laravel-7) specifically stated the following:

> The previous @component syntax for Blade components has not and will not be removed.

In line with that, I can vouch that `@component` still works fine in Laravel 9.

However, when writing new components I would recommend using the [new-style syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-components) eg `<x-alert/>` or `<x-user-profile/>`. It will make more sense for newer Laravel developers, and is the only documented solution now.

You should be fine to leave existing instances as-is if you wish; in terms of DX, Laravel's ["Blade directives"](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#blade-directives) are still very much a thing, so the `@component` syntax is far from alien; my blade templates have loads of `@something` throughout.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "new style" syntax?

Comment: Sure; I've updated my original reply to make this clearer, but essentially I'm referring to the `<x-myComponent/>` syntax as per the current Laravel documentation.